# Websockets issue

Tags: firefox, websocket, kaazing

Here is the result from one of my desktops:

http://websocketstest.com/result/239749

Websockets are fine in Firefox, but no other connection can be made.

For some reason this website works perfectly:

http://demo.kaazing.com/forex/

In the firebug I can see that somehow kaazing streams the data and rotates the request every 500kbs.

Any ideas?

asdad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Firefox 10.0.2, released in Feb 2002 - well over a year ago. As far as WebSocket support is concerned, this feels like an eternity...

One of the biggest challenges with WebSocket as a technology is that not everybody is on the latest and greatest browser version. Users of old desktop browsers (especially IE), Android (with default browser), and older iOS will all face this challenge.

The reason why Kaazing works is that it uses clever WebSocket emulation techniques: when native WebSocket support is not available in the browser, the connectivity falls back to alternative techniques that are very close in performance to a native WebSocket connection. If interested, you can learn more about the [Kaazing emulation technology](http://blog.kaazing.com/2011/11/17/the-industrys-best-websocket-emulation-real-time-web-apps-for-all-your-customers-even-if-theyre-on-ie6/) that works in all the older browsers, including IE6.